# Using LIMIT in MySQL to limit results based on column value (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, limit

I did multiple searches for an answer to this (on SO and elsewhere), but haven't found an answer that really fit my needs (if it's out there, I apologize in advance).

I have a query, using PHP, that returns an array from a database (WordPress). Basically what I want to do is look at a column's value, and then LIMIT based on that value. Here's the array that's returned for a better idea:

http://pastebin.com/AC043qfh

In the query, you'll notice that the value for `post_parent` repeats for several of returned arrays. What I want to do is have it LIMIT to 3 based on the `post_parent` value e.g. I want 3 entries for `post_parent` 79, 87, 100, etc.

I'm not well versed (see: at all) in MySQL queries, but this is what I have to get that array:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, guid, post_parent, post_title 
FROM $wpdb->posts p 
WHERE p.post_type = 'attachment'
    AND p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'
    AND p.post_status = 'inherit'
    AND p.post_parent IN
        (SELECT object_id FROM $term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $post_term)
```

I've tried using `GROUP BY`, but that didn't get me what I wanted. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** Just to clarify, these are the results I want:
http://pastebin.com/pWXdUuXv

Comment: Could you explain the rules to your limit? I mean, I can give you a query that will limit it to three, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: @Justin Wood He did - "I want 3 entries for post_parent 79, 87, 100, etc."

Comment: I'd recommend creating a "rank" and then use a conditional based on that rank...  Changing `LIMIT` would require dynamic SQL at the least.

Comment: @Sam and like I said, I can create a query that can limit it to three, but he wants it based off of that field, which means it may not ALWAYS be a limit of three.

Comment: Your not understanding, he wants 3 rows for each unique value in the `post_parent` column. Hard to explain !

Comment: Hey all...thanks for the replies so far. Sam is correct. I always want a limit of three rows for each unique value in `post_parent`. So if there is just one entry, it will give me just that one entry, if there are 11, it will just return 3 rows.

Comment: Do you want the 3 returned rows ordered in some way?

Comment: There's a tag for this: `greatest-n-per-group`. Try searching that tag.

Comment: They don't have to be ordered at all, as I shuffle them later using `shuffle()`. My guess is the query itself pulls them in order that they're found in the db, which is appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar I did some research on greatest-n-per-group but can't see how I can translate the information for my needs. I may just have to keep researching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick:
(I'm assuming ID is unique, if not substitute something that is)

```
SELECT
  p.ID, guid, post_parent, post_title
FROM (
SELECT
  a.ID as ID,
  COUNT(*) as rank
FROM (
  SELECT ID, post_parent
  FROM $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'
    AND post_status = 'inherit'
  ) AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, post_parent
  FROM $wpdb->posts
  WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'
    AND post_status = 'inherit'
  ) AS b ON b.ID <= a.ID AND b.post_parent = a.post_parent
GROUP BY a.ID
) AS r
JOIN $wpdb->posts p ON r.ID = p.ID AND r.rank <= 3
WHERE p.post_parent IN (
  SELECT object_id FROM $term_relationships
  WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $post_term)
GROUP BY p.ID
;
```

**EDIT:** Attempt to include category in rank so it'll actually work.

Specifying conditions twice is a bit ugly, but I didn't see an easy way around it.

Comment: Yeah, `ID` is unique to each image in the DB. `post_parent` is unique to the post that the image appears on, but obviously some images will share the same `post_parent` value (considering the question at hand). I tried running this as is and I didn't get any results, however, I'll take a look at modifying it as I see what you are getting at doing.

Comment: ebyrob your edit did the trick and does exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!