# Limit data from another table attribule

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Job` and table `Company`. Each job item will be for a company. I would like to write a query that will list the jobs.

Company has a quantity column. When jobs are listed from `Job`, the number of jobs listed for a given company is the number in this `Quantity` column.
Data example

**For example:** Company A has quantity = 2. The query data will return the top 2 jobs.

How can I do this in a sql query?

Table Job

```
| id | Title | Company ID   |
|:---|------:|:------------:|
| 1  | Job 1 |   1
| 2  | Job 2 |   1
| 3  | Job 3 |   1
| 4  | Job 4 |   2
| 5  | Job 5 |   2
```

Table Company

```
| id | Title     | Quantity|
|:---|----------:|:-------:|
| 1  |  Company 1|   2
| 2  |  Company 2|   2
```

And the result of query `Select * From Job` => With condition limit quantity of company.

```
| id | Title | Company ID |
|:---|------:|:----------:|
| 1  | Job 1 |   1
| 2  | Job 2 |   1
| 4  | Job 4 |   2
| 5  | Job 5 |   2
```

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result (both as formatted text.)

Comment: Which rdbms are you using? Mysql, Sql server, something else? Also please read this and update your answer: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @BeanFrog, i using Mysql server. And version 5.6.30

Comment: If i understand you right, you would like to LIMIT the number of results based on a field value. For MySQL and PHP this was discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790566/using-limit-in-mysql-to-limit-results-based-on-column-value-php-mysql

Comment: Is there a company column in Jobs?

Comment: @ P.Salmon Yes, job has Company id

Answer (score 1):

Create procedure and you can use variable with LIMIT

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetJobs`()
    NO SQL
BEGIN

DECLARE cid INT;
DECLARE jobsLimit INT;

DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE JobListTemp (
     id INT,
     Title VARCHAR(255),
     CompanyID INT
   ) ENGINE=MEMORY;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Company INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 

  SET cId = (SELECT id FROM Company LIMIT i,1);

  SET jobsLimit = (SELECT quantity FROM Company WHERE id = cId LIMIT 1);

  INSERT INTO JobListTemp SELECT * FROM Job WHERE CompanyID = cId LIMIT jobsLimit;

  SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM JobListTemp;

DROP TABLE JobListTemp;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can query all data will that query? i see that only query for special company.

Comment: It is possible. I've updated my example. But since MySQL doesn't have declare variable as table (like MSSQL for example) you'll have to use temporary table.

Comment: Thank you for support, so i will check by code, because my task has many condition. Each condition has another query.That's simple query, and more complext, example find by category, find by keyword, find by job area

Comment: If you don't need to combine filters, you can create other procedures (use procedure params for filter values) for different search conditions to avoid adding complexity to single procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the inner sqlquery.

For example:

```
select innerTab.id,innerTab.Title,innerTab.companyid 
from (select * from job order by id limit 2) innerTab 
inner join Company on innerTab.companyid=company.companyid
```

The colname is not same with you.

So you can change it to make sure the sql can run.